# Why is NodeJS C/C++ addon faster then pure C

Tags: c++, node.js

I experiment with NodeJS Addons and I have this code in C:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    else if (n == 1) return 1;
    else return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fib(atoi(argv[1]));
}
```

And this in NodejS Addon:

JS:

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log(addon.fib(process.argv[2]));
```

C++:

```
using namespace v8;

int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    else if (n == 1) return 1;
    else return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));
}

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Uint32::New(isolate, fib(args[0]->Uint32Value())));
}

void init(Local<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "fib", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, init)
```

I try calculate fib() for number 50 and gets this results:

- Clean C: 2m 36s
- NodeJS Addon: 1m 22s

**Could anybody explain why is NodeJS Addon faster then pure C?** I'm not C/C++ expert but I assumed then pure C will be faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats not C! Learn the languages you use. How do you peofile? Read [ask], provide a [mcve]

Comment: `I'm not C/C++ expert`...nobody is, there's nothing called `c/c++`, at all., and at best, an expression like that is UB.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you compiled your `C` program by hand without specifying `-O3` or other optimization option. Whereas `node-gyp` or whatever tool was used to compile Node.js addon most certainly compiled with maximum optimization turned on.